# increase quantity if object already exists in array else add new object in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have addToCart function and it's working, increasing quantity if the object already exists else adding a new object but when I use the function on another page it's adding new object no matter what

```
const addToCart = (id, title, price) => {
    let itemIndex = cart.filter((el) => el.id === id)[0]
    if (itemIndex) {
        itemIndex.quantity++
    } else {
        let quantity = 1
        let newItem = {
            id,
            title,
            price,
            quantity,
        }
        setCart([...cart, newItem])
    }
}
```

Comment: _"when I use the function on another page"_: how do you mean? The function sets state so I would imagine it's specifically designed for the component that has that state.

Comment: Please share a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Your code is correct. in another page, please check cart array is empty or not.

Comment: by saying another page i mean another component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it. removing one `=` from filter was enough

```
cart.filter((el) => el.id == id)[0]
```

Comment: _"... removing one `=` from filter was enough."_ ... which probably is an indicator of having `id` values of similar/same objects assigned differently, once as string values and once as number values.